# Debugging a hackney request

Tags: erlang, elixir

So I'm doing something like `Logger.info "debug message"` in an iex remote console shell in an Elixir/Phoenix application (it only happens in a remote console shell) I have with a 3rd party logging service.  I kept getting an error as follows in the console after the call to Logger#info/1:

```
    iex server-xxx 3> :gen_event handler Timber.LoggerBackends.HTTP installed in Logger terminating
** (exit) an exception was raised:
    ** (ArgumentError) argument error
        (stdlib) :ets.lookup_element(:hackney_config, :mod_metrics, 2)
        (hackney) /root/project/deps/hackney/src/hackney_metrics.erl:27: :hackney_metrics.get_engine/0
        (hackney) /root/project/deps/hackney/src/hackney_connect.erl:78: :hackney_connect.create_connection/5
        (hackney) /root/project/deps/hackney/src/hackney_connect.erl:47: :hackney_connect.connect/5
        (hackney) /root/project/deps/hackney/src/hackney.erl:330: :hackney.request/5
        (timber) lib/timber/logger_backends/http.ex:396: Timber.LoggerBackends.HTTP.transmit_buffer/2
        (timber) lib/timber/logger_backends/http.ex:211: Timber.LoggerBackends.HTTP.handle_info/2
        (stdlib) gen_event.erl:577: :gen_event.server_update/4
```

I traced it down to this request to hackney (which is Erlang, and I don't know much about):

```
 :hackney.request(method, url, req_headers, body, req_opts)
```

end

Here are the arguments I'm passing with the auth token sanitized (culled from a remote debugging session):

```
    < _req_headers@1 = [{<<"Authorization">>,
                     <<"Basic MXXXXAUTH">>},
                    {<<"Content-Type">>,<<"application/msgpack">>},
                    {<<"User-Agent">>,<<"timber-elixir/">>}]
< _req_opts@1 = [{connect_timeout,5000},{recv_timeout,10000},{async,true}]
< _method@1 = post
< _headers@1 = #{<<"Authorization">> =>
                     <<"Basic MXXXXAUTH">>,
                 <<"Content-Type">> => <<"application/msgpack">>,
                 <<"User-Agent">> => <<"timber-elixir/">>}
< _url@1 = <<"https://logs.timber.io/frames">>
< _method@1 = post
< _headers@1 = #{<<"Authorization">> =>
                     <<"Basic MXXXXAUTH">>,
                 <<"Content-Type">> => <<"application/msgpack">>,
                 <<"User-Agent">> => <<"timber-elixir/">>}
< _body@1 = [145,
             [133,
              [[167|<<"context">>],
               130,
               [[167|<<"runtime">>],
                134,
                [[171|<<"application">>],192],
                [[164|<<"file">>],163|<<"iex">>],
                [[168|<<"function">>],192],
                [[164|<<"line">>],23],
                [[171|<<"module_name">>],192],
                [[166|<<"vm_pid">>],169|<<"<0.346.0>">>]],
               [[166|<<"system">>],
                130,
                [[168|<<"hostname">>],192],
                [[163|<<"pid">>]|<<"Íºê">>]]],
              [[162|<<"dt">>],187|<<"2019-05-07T15:52:04.393107Z">>],
              [[165|<<"event">>],192],
              [[165|<<"level">>],164|<<"info">>],
              [[167|<<"message">>],166|<<"help 7">>]]]
< _req_headers@1 = [{<<"Authorization">>,
                     <<"Basic MXXXXAUTH">>},
                    {<<"Content-Type">>,<<"application/msgpack">>},
                    {<<"User-Agent">>,<<"timber-elixir/">>}]
< _body@1 = [145,
             [133,
              [[167|<<"context">>],
               130,
               [[167|<<"runtime">>],
                134,
                [[171|<<"application">>],192],
                [[164|<<"file">>],163|<<"iex">>],
                [[168|<<"function">>],192],
                [[164|<<"line">>],23],
                [[171|<<"module_name">>],192],
                [[166|<<"vm_pid">>],169|<<"<0.346.0>">>]],
               [[166|<<"system">>],
                130,
                [[168|<<"hostname">>],192],
                [[163|<<"pid">>]|<<"Íºê">>]]],
              [[162|<<"dt">>],187|<<"2019-05-06T12:52:04.393107Z">>],
              [[165|<<"event">>],192],
              [[165|<<"level">>],164|<<"info">>],
              [[167|<<"message">>],166|<<"debug message">>]]]
< _req_headers@1 = [{<<"Authorization">>,
                     <<"Basic MXXXXAUTH">>},
                    {<<"Content-Type">>,<<"application/msgpack">>},
                    {<<"User-Agent">>,<<"timber-elixir/">>}]
< _req_opts@1 = [{connect_timeout,5000},{recv_timeout,10000},{async,true}]
< _req_opts@1 = [{connect_timeout,5000},{recv_timeout,10000},{async,true}]
```

How do I identify the "bad argument" that is causing the issue? I'm pretty new to Erlang.

Comment: I tried googling that error message, and found [this comment](https://github.com/mweibel/facebook.ex/issues/67#issuecomment-457551099), which suggests that the Hackney application might not be started. Try `Application.ensure_all_started(:hackney)`.

Comment: Thank you I did an Application.started_applications/1 in the iex console on the remote environment and it showed `hackney` in the list...so it appeared to be started...

Comment: (I don't know much about hackney, but...) It seems like the problem is caused by hackney trying to lookup its metrics engine (`:ets.lookup_element(:hackney_config, :mod_metrics, 2)`) - perhaps it didn't register that for whatever reason? Might be a bug in hackney or some misconfiguration? I would start by manually trying `:ets.lookup_element(:hackney_config, :mod_metrics, 2)` and `:hackney_metrics.get_engine/0` in the remote environment. You can also `:ets.tab2list(:hackney_config)` to look at the whole table.

Comment: Thank you @PawełObrok - when I do `:ets.lookup_element(:hackney_config, :mod_metrics, 2)` in the remote console, I get {:metrics_ng, :metrics_dummy} instead of the ArgumentError. But doing the `Logger.info "debug message"` still triggers the ArgumentError somehow. You've given me some ideas though,thank you.